# How can I import JavaScript code into the developer tools in the browser? One time forever

Tags: javascript, browser, developer-tools

I used to hide end screen cards in YouTube with code in the console, but it works until reloading or closing the tab. So, how can I import JavaScript code one time for all times?

Comment: What do you mean `code in Control`? Is Control some application?

Comment: My best guess is that you're trying to inject Javascript code into a website permanently every time you visit that website. You'll need a browser addon for this. Probably Greasemonkey or Tempermonkey (depending on which browser you use).

Comment: @CertainPerformance I write script in "Console" :))

Comment: So do you mean `Control-V`?

Comment: The attention was due to a meta question. But which one?

Comment: @PeterMortensen https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420890/is-there-a-canonical-question-where-asker-doesnt-know-what-a-browser-extension?cb=1

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to type in and run a script every time you load a page, you can use a userscript instead. Userscript code runs automatically when a page matching the page you want loads. For example:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name             No Youtube Endcards
// @include          /^https://youtube\.com/watch
// @grant            none
// ==/UserScript==

console.log('Put your script here...');
```

You'll need a userscript manager like [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/). Install the addon, click on the "Create a new script" button, paste in the metadata block above, and then continue writing the JS as needed.